# Kendo grid update window zoom effect broken

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I had a web-based grid in KendoUI previous version, and now refresh the KendoUI to the Kendo Web 2012 Q3, but the grid which worked in the previous version, generates a bug: When I trying to open Update or Create window, it's start with 0.01 scaling (CSS3, I think), and it's NOT animating to 1 scaling, stays on 0.01.

[image: You can see it in this picture].

The temporary solution is now the "switch off" the zoom effect, rewrite this row:

```
createToggleEffect("zoom", "scale", 0.01);
```

to

```
createToggleEffect("zoom", "scale", 1);
```

on `kendo.web.js` file, in row number 3780, but I want back my zoom effect.

It's a documented bug, or my mistake? Can anyone help me how can I fix it?

PS: I tested it on Chromium and Firefox, both shows the bug.

Comment: Would you mind posting some code or even better sharing something in jsfiddle that shows the effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue that is caused by a change in the css() method behavior between jQuery 1.7 and 1.8. We fixed the issue in the latest internal builds, but as a workaround you can just upgrade to jQuery 1.8 and the issue will go away.